# How to prove the power rule using logarithmic differentiation, but without implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

So, I have a question on my assignment that requires me to *"use the properties of logs and exponents"* to prove the power rule using logarithmic differentiation. But, I don't know how to. I scrounged the internet and haven't been able to get an answer. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your work please.

Comment: I only did it using implicit differentiation, but the question is telling me not to do that. Other than that, I haven't been able to figure out much aside from taking the exponents on both sides to isolate y, but, in the end, I still have to use normal differentiation to get the rule. If I want to show my work, should I edit the post? I'm sorry, I'm new.

Comment: If $x>0$ then $x^n=e^{n\log(x)}$.

Comment: Yes, now I want the derivative of that to equal r.n^(r-1), somehow.